# Jenkins, Docker and Kubernetes (using minikube)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have already used Jenkins in the past integrated with GitHub and deploying zip file to AWS Elastic beanstalk.

I am new to kubernetes, how can I make full CI/CD pipeline to create dockers images from jenkins and deploying it to kubernetes cluster running minikube.

Any links, experiences from experts or guidance will be appreciated

Regards,
Aziz

Comment: https://itnext.io/deploy-jenkins-with-dynamic-slaves-in-minikube-8aef5404e9c1

Answer (score 2):

We're working on an open source project called [Jenkins X](https://jenkins-x.io/) which is a proposed sub project of the Jenkins foundation aimed at automating CI/CD on Kubernetes using Jenkins pipelines and GitOps for promotion across environments.

If you want to see how to automate CI/CD with multiple environments on Kubernetes using GitOps for promotion between environments and Preview Environments on Pull Requests you might wanna check out [my recent talk on Jenkins X at DevOxx UK](https://jenkins-x.io/demos/devoxx-uk-2018/) where I do a live demo of this on GKE. Though Jenkins X works on [AWS, AKS and GKE and other kubernetes clusters like minikube too](https://jenkins-x.io/getting-started/).

The only issue on minikube is there's no webhooks so it can take a while for promotion to kick in (there's a 5 minute backup poll for git events). You can manually trigger the jobs in the Jenkins UI though to work around the lack of webhooks ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple stages in this workflow.

1. Checkout the source code from Github and build a Docker image from a Dockerfile.
2. Push the resulting image to a remote Docker image registery such as Dockerhub.
3. Deploy the image to the Kubernetes cluster.

It doesn't matter if kubernetes is running on Minikube or some other cloud platform. To deploy to a kubernetes cluster you can either use `kubectl` or the [Jenkins Kubernetes Continuous Deploy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Kubernetes+Continuous+Deploy+Plugin).

Comment: Regarding step1 and step2, jenkins will create docker image using Dockerfile ?
and push to docker hub will also be by jenkins ?

Comment: The standard thing is to have a Dockerfile as part of the source code repository. On the jenkins server you would then have Docker installed, and jenkins would simply run a `docker build` followed 
by a `docker push` command. That is how you would acheive points 1 and 2.